# How to use split on individual entries in a list

Tags: python, list, url

So I have a python list (called lst in the snippet below) of urls.

```
/this/is/the/first/url/file.zip
/this/is/the/second/url/file.zip
...
```

I want to create another list of only the /file.zip part of each url. So far I have this:

```
lst2 = []
for i in lst:
    lst2.append(i[0].split('/')][-1])
```

and it returns the /file.zip part as expected. But my question is how can I do this for the entire list?

Comment: What is `lst` here?

Comment: It's the python list that contains the urls.  I edited the post for clarification

Comment: @Wintro.  That's the same recipe I thought would work too but I get this message when I run it: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I do not understand **how** your code can work "as expected", it is buggy as explained by Wintro.

Comment: @e9e9s are you sure you are putting it exactly as it is? It is working normally for me in Python2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: Yes, I literally copied and pasted it into my notebook and I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: If the base code is exactly as I wrote it down there, make sure that your `lst` is a 1-dimentional list. `lst = ["/path/to/file.zip", "/path/to/file2.zip"]`.

Comment: It wasn't.  I append all the urls to the list at the same time rather than append 1 url then extend the rest of them to the list.  It looked like: lst = [["/path/to/file.zip", "/path/to/file2.zip"]]   Out of curiousity, what's meant by 1-dimensional?

Comment: A one dimensional list essentially means that it has no lists inside of it. So its assessor will only be `my_list[i]`. You can read more about lists and their "2-dimentionality" [here](http://bjc.berkeley.edu/bjc-r/cur/programming/python/2D_lists.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `lst = [url1, url2, ...]`, your current code is very close to working optimally.

The last line of the code `lst2.append(i[0].split('/')][-1])` is where the problems lie.

By calling `i[0]` you are essentially getting the first character of the `i` string (since the `i` derives from the strings inside `lst`), and then splitting it based on `/`, which would not work. Then you have an error with the lone `]` after the `split`.

So, to fix this code, here is what you would do.

```
lst2 = []
for i in lst:
    lst2.append(i.split('/')[-1])
```

and then, printing `lst2` would give

> ['file.zip', 'file1.zip', ...]

which is your desired output.

---

To explain, `i in lst` is getting every item inside the `lst` list, which are strings. Then, inside the loop, the string `i` is being split according to the `/` inside it, which generates another array. But you want the final part of that string, hence the final item in the array, which can be accessed using `[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
lst2 = [url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] for url in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
lst = [
'/this/is/the/url/file.zip',
'/this/is/the/url/file1.zip',
'/this/is/the/url/file2.zip',
'/this/is/the/url/file3.zip',
'/this/is/the/url/file4.zip',
]

lst2 = [l.split('/')[-1] for l in lst]
```

`lst2` now looks like this:

```
['file.zip', 'file1.zip', 'file2.zip', 'file3.zip', 'file4.zip']
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Wintro answer:

Do you need the leading '/' in your results (/file1.zip) ? Then you have to preprend it again because `split()` will make it disappear.

I suggest that you use python builtin `pathlib` or `os.path.basename` or `os.path.split`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Also, you can use loop comprehension:

```
urllst = ["url1/file1.zip", "url2/file2.zip", "..."]
filelst = ['/' + url.split('/')[-1] for url in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be necessary in this case, it is always a good idea to use the proper library for these functions. In this case, that is the `os` module:

```
>>> import os
>>> [os.path.basename(i) for i in lst]
['file.zip', 'file1.zip', 'file2.zip', 'file3.zip', 'file4.zip']
```